# Rate at which electric field is established after creation of potential difference in a circuit

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields

My friend presented me with this thought experiment: Imagine a simple large circuit(say load is a bulb). Now if circuit is closed the bulb lights up instantly, implying information travelling faster than light.

Clearly there's something fishy.

As we are are taught, electric field is established, charge carriers will move all over the circuit.
From my understanding it had to do something with the rate at which electric field itself is established.
I might not have adequate knowledge to go on more about this topic, but I'm here to learn.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question, but not a new one! See [my answer to this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/652921/why-does-electric-field-remain-confined-to-a-wire/652955#652955) for a fairly detailed account of what happens. If you want to follow up with more detail then add a new comment.